# How can I set -arch=sm_NN of nvcc in my CMake configuration?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I have a .cu file which uses `atomicCAS` with inputs `(unsigned short *, unsigned short, unsigned short)`. My environment is with `--gpu-code=sm_86,sm_86,sm_61`. It occurs compile error under the default cuda architecture.

I tested using `nvcc -arch=sm_86 my.cu`, this funciton could be compiled successfully. So, how could I set `-arch=sm_86` of nvcc in my CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: What CMake version do you have installed, and what did you specify in your root CMakeLists.txt file's `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION)`?

Comment: We use ```3.20.6``` with ```cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)```

Comment: It would be good to set the required to at least `3.18` when using CUDA, as many CUDA related features arrived with `3.18` and previous versions.

Answer (score 2):

In CMake 3.18 and above, you do this by setting the architecture numbers in [the `CUDA_ARCHITECTURES` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CUDA_ARCHITECTURES.html) (which is default initialized according to [the `CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES` variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES.html#variable:CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES)) to a semicolon separated list (CMake uses semicolons as its list entry separator character).

From the docs' Examples section:

> ```
> set_target_properties(tgt PROPERTIES CUDA_ARCHITECTURES "35;50;72")
> ```
>
> Generates code for real and virtual architectures 30, 50 and 72.
>
> ```
> set_property(TARGET tgt PROPERTY CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 70-real 72-virtual)
> ```
>
> Generates code for real architecture 70 and virtual architecture 72.
>
> ```
> set_property(TARGET tgt PROPERTY CUDA_ARCHITECTURES OFF)
> ```
>
> CMake will not pass any architecture flags to the compiler.

The source code that sets the build command with the `sm_` argument for the Makefile generator can be found in [`Source/cmMakefileTargetGenerator.cxx`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmMakefileTargetGenerator.cxx):

```cpp
void cmMakefileTargetGenerator::WriteDeviceLinkRule(
  std::vector<std::string>& commands, const std::string& output)
{
  std::string architecturesStr =
    this->GeneratorTarget->GetSafeProperty("CUDA_ARCHITECTURES");
  ...
  std::vector<std::string> architectures = cmExpandedList(architecturesStr);
  ...
  for (const std::string& architectureKind : architectures) {
    ...
    const std::string architecture =
      architectureKind.substr(0, architectureKind.find('-'));
    ...
    std::string command = cmStrCat(
      this->Makefile->GetRequiredDefinition("CMAKE_CUDA_DEVICE_LINKER"),
      " -arch=sm_", architecture, registerFileCmd, " -o=$@ ",
      cmJoin(linkDeps, " "));
    localGen->WriteMakeRule(*this->BuildFileStream, nullptr, cubin, linkDeps,
                            { command }, false);
  }
  ...
}
```

Otherwise, you can just use `target_compile_options` or `add_compile_options`.

Also slightly related: the `CUDA_SELECT_NVCC_ARCH_FLAGS` function in the `FindCUDA` module (deprecated since version 3.10, which added CUDA language support into CMake).

Related CUDA docs: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#options-for-steering-gpu-code-generation

Note also that since CMake v3.24, there is the `native` value for `CUDA_ARCHITECTURES`: "*Compile for the architecture(s) of the host's GPU(s).*"

Comment: Maybe we have some other problems because ```__CUDA_ARCH__``` is always 520 while```--gpu-code=sm_86,sm_86,sm_61``` Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Sakura what do you expect to see? Is this still part of the question posted here or is it 
a separate/new problem? If it's a separate problem and this specific problem here is solved, post a new question post. otherwise, edit your question post here to provide enough detail to actually fully understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but the cmake command does not work because the ```__CUDA_ARCH__``` is always 520, which is supposed to >700

Comment: @Sakura what exactly did you do to try to apply the information in this answer post?

Comment: I want to add related command in CMakeLists.txt so that ```__CUDA_ARCH__```>700. as what ```nvcc -arch=sm_86``` dose

Comment: @Sakura No. I mean- how did you set the `CUDA_ARCHITECTURES` target property, and what exactly did you set it to?

Comment: sry I have misunderstanding. I tested```set_target_properties(${LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES CUDA_ARCHITECTURES "87;86")```, as well as ```set_property(TARGET ${LIB_NAME} PROPERTY CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 86)```

Comment: @Sakura As a first step I would recommend checking if the flags are being set the way you expect. E.g. if you are generating a Makefile use `make VERBOSE=1`. Another idea would be to try the global option `cmake -DCMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES="87;86" ..`to see if you are e.g. not applying the property to the right target(s).

Comment: Thanks. ```set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};-gencode arch=compute_86,code=sm_86)``` works for me,.